# Can an item toveled by someone non-religious be used?

Tags: blessing, mikvah-ritual-bath, tevilas-keilim-dipping, non-religious

If a cooking pot was expressly intentionally toveled in a kosher mikva by someone who is not religious (intentionally does not keep shabbat, kosher etc.) and did not make a blessing, but followed all other requirements (eg. removed labels) is the pot considered toveled? The fact that the item was toveled can be independently corroborated (3rd party or video camera etc.)

Possibly related: [Can someone [be] tovel accidentally? (Does tovelling need kavanah?)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/can-someone-be-tovel-accidentally-does-tovelling-need-kavanah)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *t'vila* (immersion) of objects requires no special intent or indeed human action at all and is valid even if the object fell into the water (*Aruch Hashulchan* 120:12). However, an adult [religious] Jew must have seen the immersion to ensure it took place (*Rama* :14–15), though *Aruch Hashulchan* (:13) says a minor suffices when immersing glass [or porcelain], as it requires immersion only by rabbinical decree; I don't know whether video surveillance suffices for this.